# How to catch errors in synchronous functions in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronization

In asynchronous functions, we can simply catch the error in callback. For example :

Async func:

```
fs.readdir(path, function(err){
    //catch error
)
```

As synchronous functions don't have callback, how can I catch errors?

Sync func:

```
fs.readdirSync(path);           //throws some error
```

One way is to use try catch block:

```
try{
    fs.readdirSync(path);
}
catch(err){
    //do whatever with error
}
```

Is there any other way to do that? If yes, then which one is better?

Comment: `try...catch` is the synchronous way.

Comment: for synchronous try ... catch is the way to handle exception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any other way to do that?

No, that's how you do it. Typically you have all your main logic in the `try`, and then just handle exceptional conditions (errors) in the `catch`. (And cleanup in the `finally`.)